# Kivy Sending text from spinner to another function

Tags: python, kivy

I've been trying to figure out how to get the value selected in a spinner into another function.  I basically need a user to select some option and then press "save" prompting another function to write the data to a file (right now I just have it setup to print). When I run the form.finkle function it prints kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x02C149D0

I'm sure its an easy fix, but I've been stuck on it for days.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

condspin = Spinner(text='Condition',values=('Good','Fair','Poor','Missing'))
typespin = Spinner(text='Type', values=('Metal','Wood','Pin','Missing'))
commlabel = Label(text='Comment')       
commtext = TextInput(text="")

class Goose(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2,rows=6,padding=10,spacing=10)    
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Hunter Parking'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Boat Launch'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='ETRAP'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Monument',on_press=form.monform))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Camp Site'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Sign'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Building'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Trail Head'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Dam'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Day Use'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Pavilion'))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Misc Point'))
        return layout

class form():    
    def finkle(condtest):
        print condtest

    def monform(self):
        monbox = GridLayout(cols=2,rows=8,padding=20,spacing=20)
        monpopup = Popup(title="Monument",content=monbox)
        closebut = Button(text="Close")
        closebut.bind(on_press=monpopup.dismiss)
        savebut = Button(text="Save Point")
        savebut.bind(on_press=form.finkle)
        condtest = condspin.text
        monbox.add_widget(condspin)
        monbox.add_widget(typespin)
        monbox.add_widget(commlabel)
        monbox.add_widget(commtext)
        monbox.add_widget(savebut)
        monbox.add_widget(closebut)

        monpopup.open()

Goose().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have made the spinner global, you could just do `print(condspin.text)`. More generally, you could pass the spinner as an argument, e.g.

```
from functools import partial
savebut.bind(on_press=partial(self.finkle, condspin))
```

and redefine the finkle method as

```
def finkle(self, spinner, button)
```

Note that I changed form.finkle to self.finkle and added both the self and spinner arguments. It's bad practice to call the method via the class like that.

There are some significant other bad style things in your code, and I would recommend some other changes. Mostly I would make use of kv language for basically everything, it will make the widget trees much clearer, more robust to changes later, and also make this binding very simple (you'd be able to refer to the spinner text via a kv id). Also, the form class is semi-unnecessary, you could replace it with a FormWidget that is the GridLayout you make in the monform function, adding all its children and behaviour in kv.

Comment: Thanks inclement!  Sorry for the poor style. I'm pretty new to python and programming in general.